Stop and rebuild a single service in a running docker compose stack
I have a docker-compose.yaml file with a bunch of services that make up an app:
services:
  mongo:
  redis:
  rabbitmq:
  typesense:
  app-01:
  app-02:
  app-lb:

Here app-lb is a haproxy container load balancing app-01 and app-02.
The idea was that I could stop either one of them, build, and bring up. Then do the same with the other one, without any downtime.
docker compose stop app-01
docker compose build app-01
docker compose start app-01

But this is not working, it will just start the old container.
After the build I can do docker compose up, but that will also restart/recreate all the other services, causing downtime.
Is this possible?

do a docker ps -a, find the stopped container and docker rm this container. This should do the trick.

You should be able to
docker compose build app-01
docker compose up -d

You can always build a new image, even if a container is running off of the old image.  The old image will stay available until it is manually removed, and it can't be removed as long as it has running containers.
docker compose up will look at all of the container definitions and compare them to the running containers.  If any containers' setups have changed, those containers will be deleted and recreated (and this is normal practice, the container itself should not be important).
You should rarely if ever need docker compose stop and start.  These bring a container into an unusual state where the container exists but is not running a process.  docker compose start (and docker start) restart the process in the existing container; this may result in problems since the container filesystem will not be in a "clean" state.  In your particular setup, since it reuses the existing container, it will also reuse the existing (old) image.
